# How “drmModeGetResources” works?

Tags: display-resolution, gpu, drm, kms

Ubuntu 22.04

I’ve been trying to flow a instruction to change my resolution while the normal ways doesn’t work.

The instruction says “You can enumerate the available KMS modes if you read from the KMS file descriptor using the open syscall. Using that you can control the GPU. drmModeGetResources(drm_fd) will return a struct with several unint32 items including framebuffers, crtcs, connectors, encoders, resolutions, ect…”

I’m not sure if I understood it correctly, I’m not sure how to “read from the KMS file descriptor using the open syscall”, I tried to install command “ drmModeGetResources” through apt install, it returns “unable to locate package drmModeGetResources”.

Can anybody give me some tips how that instruction means and what commands should I actually run?

Comment: `drmModeGetResources` is a library call not an executable command - to use it, you'd need to install the `libdrm-dev` package and write some C code